# How to change User Gitlab in terminal and Sign in another user

Tags: gitlab

I have already logged in with user in AndroidStudio in Gitlab, as I am working a project, and while I pushing the code and create a branch it shows the old logged in user have pushed the branch, however I working with different email, Now I need to logout from the old user and the new user to able to push the code with the correct one

Answer (score 0):

Try using command

> git config -e

then then find the section [remote "origin"]
and add new account name before "gitlab.com/...

example:

```
[remote "origin"]
        url = https://myacc@gitlab.com/...
```

and then saving file.